# JQueryMobile - position and size of select menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working on a JQueryMobile page. This page will contain a select element (dropdown) with a custom menu. I am trying to position the menu right below the select button and as well change its width to the width of the select button. Further stylizing will follow as well.

In Firebug I figured out that JQM changes the CSS classes of the select menu (here: select-choice-1-listbox-popup) as well as its position attributes. I thought it might be the proper approach to get this element and simply change the top attribute.
This doesn't work though. I guess my code is executed too early because the first alert does not show a value for the "top" attribute.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function positionMenu() {
        alert(document.getElementById('select-choice-1-listbox-popup').style.top); // prints ""
        document.getElementById('select-choice-1-listbox-popup').style.top="300px";
        alert(document.getElementById('select-choice-1-listbox-popup').style.top); // prints "300px"
    }
</script>
```

[...]

```html
<div onClick="positionMenu();"  data-role="fieldcontain" style="width:300px;">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select data-native-menu=false name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My question is: How can I change the attributes of a select menu?

Comment: This is something that endless "_Googling_" has borne no fruit!